# create environment from .yml file using pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, virtualenv

I have a file which has the environmental requirements in yml format. I want to read the file so as I can install the required dependencies using pip as we using txt file.

```
pip  install -r requirement.txt
```

this what the yml file looks like after parsing uing pyaml.

```
{'name': 'tables-detr',
'channels': ['conda-forge', 'pytorch', 'defaults'], 
'dependencies': ['python=3.6.10', 'pip', 'pytorch==1.5.0', 'cudatoolkit==10.1.243', 'jupyter', 'ipykernel', 'torchvision==0.6.0', 'pandas==0.25.3', 'opencv==4.1.2', 'scikit-learn==0.21.3', 'tqdm==4.39.0', 'itkwidgets==0.23.1', 'cython', 'numpy==1.17',
 {'pip': ['scikit-image', 'git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools&subdirectory=PythonAPI', 'tensorboard==2.0.1', 'tensorboardx==1.9', 'scipy==1.1.0', 'jupytext==1.3.0', 'PyMuPDF==1.16.14']}]}
```

I don't if I am making things harder for me but my intention is to use the same file(in some way) created using conda to create the same environment using pip.
Need Help!

Answer (score 0):

The yaml file is because you should install it with conda not with pip. If you want to install with pip you must filtere out name and channel from the yaml file and create a requirements txt with only dependencies and pip